Axioms of Thought and Intelligence
Axioms of Thought and Intelligence
Objective: Investigating Human Foolishness
Investigation of Human Intelligence from the Perspective of Axiomatic Theory
Axioms and Definitions of the Axiomatic Theory of Thought:

Smart Person: A person who is capable of critiquing their own ideas and axioms of thought, and who can distinguish between facts and beliefs.

Foolish Person: A person who does not critique their own axioms, insists on knowledge based on their own axioms, and tries to defend their beliefs using their knowledge.

Mind: The mind is a system of axioms; a set of axioms.

Axiom: Axiom refers to fundamental beliefs of a person that they tend to overlook when making choices; basic statements from which all others derive; within the mind of a person, these axioms are considered absolute truths, even if they are not.

Children’s Brain: The child’s brain can change axioms very quickly; the older a person gets, the harder it becomes to do this.

Each Rational Person: Every rational person has axioms of thought.

Rational Person: A person who is selfaware and capable of thought.

Thinking: The process of processing information, through which the incoming data is verified, synthesized, and deduced, or data is taken from within and outputted through logic.

Axioms of Two People: The axioms of two people can differ, even if their interests are similar; the axioms of two people cannot be absolutely identical; there are always small differences.

Knowledge: Knowledge overlays axioms.


Reasoning
Every rational person has axioms of thought, and such a set of axioms exists uniquely for each individual. Axioms of thought are formed in childhood; the child’s brain can adapt to new information much faster than an adult’s. The slower the formation of new axioms and the change of old ones, the more firmly established in consciousness are the axioms that have not changed. Therefore, with age, a person acquires a set of axioms that is resistant to change. If a child experiences a paranormal event, even if it did not occur, the child might create an axiom that the paranormal exists. This hypothetical child will grow up, and their axioms will change slowly or not at all, making the axiom about the paranormal a primary and resistant belief. If such a person acquires all the knowledge of the world, they will deny it, as knowledge overlays axioms; i.e., knowledge that confirms axioms is accepted, otherwise rejected. Therefore, such a person will continue to assert that the paranormal exists; for us, this is a belief, but in their mind, this assertion is the truth. A person who does not question their own axioms is at a disadvantage because, if they acquire a false axiom, they will defend it for the rest of their life; they will be convinced of a falsehood, which is detrimental. Therefore, a smart person is the negation of the qualities of a fool; a smart person is able to adjust their axioms to facts.
Analogy
To illustrate my point:
"The room is empty, and in the center of the room was a mechanism that worked around the clock! The mechanism was made long ago and worked perfectly. But five years ago, I began to notice that the mechanism was not working; I decided to check: it turns out the mechanism was not working because someone had placed an immense number of books on it! The mechanism began to work worse each day. I moved these books to another room, and now the mechanism works perfectly! Every day I have to remove books from the mechanism, but I have no other choice. This is my job."
A smart person is someone who can critique their own axioms; such people tend to rational, logical explanations of information; therefore, their axioms are adjusted to facts, not the other way around. Thus, they can ensure that their axioms work for knowledge, whereas if knowledge only serves to support axioms, it is less valuable on its own if the only thing it can do is serve to satisfy a person’s desire for the world to be as they want to see it. Even a smart person has axioms that are not easy to get rid of; it requires working every day.
What Next?
One may logically ask: what is the purpose of this?
That is a good question; I will try to answer:
"Suppose you meet, at first glance, a rather intelligent person; let’s say it is a university professor; indeed, a person with a brilliant mind. You want to get to know them, and you succeed. You talked about mathematics, logic, and so on, and suddenly, the topic shifts to the paranormal, and the professor claims that the paranormal exists, and moreover, that they have seen it with their own eyes. You are perplexed and ask yourself one question: how can such an intelligent person believe in such nonsense? You are disappointed."
It has always annoyed me that smart people can believe in nonsense, and in their system of coordinates, this belief is not a belief but a true assertion, and they can prove this assertion within their system of coordinates. But the facts do not match; they believe they can. Faith is an irrational belief that is accepted without evidence and is recognized as such. But if a person believes they have proven a false belief; if a person is convinced that within their system of coordinates, they can prove what they want – this is absurd. This cannot be called belief in the conventional sense; it is much deeper, it is an axiom.
If we continue to analyze the situation with the professor and their belief in the paranormal, what conclusion should we reach? Is the professor foolish or a smart person with oddities?
Human Intelligence
If a person wants to be smarter, the only way to achieve this is to think through facts that have evidence. Every axiom of thought should be subjected to criticism; if an axiom has withstood criticism, it does not mean it is true; it is possible that the person intentionally selected facts to confirm their point of view. A smart person is an inconsistent person. Intelligence has the property of rising and falling: if a person has changed their axioms throughout their life, used only facts and logic, but in old age begins to believe in nonsense, then their intelligence has evidently decreased. Being smart or foolish is a choice a person makes; therefore, it is permissible to judge such a person.
As I said earlier, books and the mechanism should be in different rooms for the mechanism to work actively and benefit knowledge. A smart person is one who can distinguish between absurd beliefs and facts and place facts in one room while discarding absurd beliefs, so that the mechanism can work at its maximum efficiency. Changes in axioms should not be limited to the individual; all axioms a person has should be subject to change.

Is your first question asking whether there have been any philosophies that have pointed out that people have axioms, including incorrect ones that lead them to reject certain facts? If yes, you may need to look at Festinger's concept of cognitive dissonance, which is psychology rather than philosophy. If you are not interested in psychological concepts, could you make that explicit in your question?

You should find Carl Jung and his archetypes of  relevance. In particular start with the child archetype and the "inner child"

@andrós No he's not saying ppl can be wrong. He's saying ppls truths are a function of their axioms.  These axioms are for the most part subconscious. And there is no possibility of axiom-less truths

@Rushi thank you

Psychology community is probably a better place to ask - since the Q. belongs more to  science than philosophy.

It sounds like you're just describing "indoctrination". "Get them while they're young and you've got them for life."

Related: Cognitive bias, and more specifically conservatism bias, belief perseverance and confirmation bias, which all relate to insufficiently revising one's belief given new evidence. Aside from biases, building on what you were taught growing up is just how learning works. Unlearning wrong things can be hard. And "smart" doesn't mean good at critical thinking.

You probably heard the expression: "Open your mind".
By opening your mind, you start the process when your brain collects, organizes, processes and connects information in subconscious, without your direct involvement. Then, all of a sudden, you get new ideas and deeper understanding, wondering where it came from.
So the million-dollar question is how to trigger this process (opening your mind).
As you correctly noticed, the way your brains were filled up in your childhood is an important ingredient of this recipe.

Gurdjieff once remarked: "Protestant(ism) is stupid (compared to Catholicism) because it has nothing for children."

Sadly, when we hear the phrase "Open your mind", then in the overwhelming majority of the cases it's spoken by activists, or even charlatans or cultists, urging us to disbelieve everything we learned and to unquestioningly believe whatever they want us to believe.

I recommend to study the work of Jean Piaget on the cognitive development of children, see Piaget's theory of cognitive development.
Children develop and also change what you call “childhood axioms”. When growing up and during their education. Children are not shaped by primordial “axioms” alike to their being shaped by the human evolution.

There is a nice anecdote by Marvin Minsky about how one of his 5-yr old twins replied when a student of Piaget was visiting them and did the water jar experiment with one of them - retold also in https://people.csail.mit.edu/katiebyl/kb/apfiles/extended_teaching_survey.pdf (about Piaget and Papert).

So evolution is your axiom. I put it at the same level as Genesis, Vishnu-in-Vaikuntha, Big Bang and so on. Colorful stories. I guess you could say "story" is my axiom.  We call it maya

Thank you very much.

@Rushi Could you please elaborate a bit why putting evolution at the same level as Genesis or Vishnu-in-Vaikuntha? Do you consider the theory of evolution a "colourful story" from biology? Thanks.

There is exact science and speculative science. Likewise religion (and philosophy). Jesus died and was resurrected — speculation. Feed the poor, turm the other cheek etc — exact. Likewise a modern astronomer can predict the next eclipse to the second (or is it millisecond?) whereas 14 billoon from big bang is speculation. Likewise I consider evolution to be speculation — look up "gaps in the fossil record"

OTOH I regard the view of Genesis as a creation myth to be the characteristic dumb stupidity if scientism-ists, on par with say, I telling you Cinderella and you interrupt me mid sentence with «"Once upon a time" is wrong grammar, you must say "At one time..."». Perhaps the point of Genesis are the stories like Cane n Abel, replayed as Issac n Ishmael and continuing today in Israel-Palestine. Also in a different culture Pandavas n Kauravas. In other words mythology to indicate eternal archetypes.

About evolution more specifically

Now, one thing to take into account is the fact that belief is not required in order to know anything at all. In fact, we can be belief-less yet still understand facts. For example, it is a fact that the color blue is blue, and pink is pink. These are quantifications that do not require belief in the slightest. Thusly, it is not that my childhood belief of blue and pink formed my understanding, rather it is the fact that blue is a color, and pink is a color as well. In fact, these colors have been around for at least 40,000 years. This is of course according to things such as cave paintings.
Now, there are indeed philosophies based upon this, in fact, scientology is a field that praises belief having shaped your entire worldview. Thusly, it strives to eradicate such a thing, in the name of progress. Unfortunately, it relies upon one thinking belief as necessary. Which, logically, is not necessary at all. Proper agnosticism is a prime example of this. The proper agnostic is one that allows for knowledge to persist without any belief being required. If you have questions pertaining how this could be, inquiry into Robert Anton Wilsons work would be sufficient. Surely, there are other writers as well, however, he is a good introduction.
